# How can i check if the child object has the id inside it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have seller and buyer information inside an array, i need to check if the id matches with either seller or buyer id inside the array, then i need to remove the object from the array.

here is the array:

```
[
  {
    "transactionId": null,
    "buyer": {
      "userId": "eu-central-1",
      "email": "pic@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "1",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf8"
    },
    "seller": {
      "userId": "eu-central-2",
      "email": "pic2@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "2",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf7"
    }
  }
]
```

i have the userid **`eu-central-2`**. i want the **`expected output`** as,

```
[
  {
    "transactionId": null,
    "user": {
      "userId": "eu-central-1",
      "email": "pic@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "1",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf8"
    } 
  }
]
```

what i tried

```
  let data = results.filter(result=> seller.userId || buyer.userId == userId);
```

the problem is the removal part and renaming the User.

Comment: `a == x || b == x`

Comment: @Andreas how to remove?

Comment: Check the duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following code:

```
results.map(result => ({ 
        transactionId: result.transactionId, 
        user: [result.buyer, result.seller]
            [1-[result.buyer, result.seller].findIndex(user => user.userId === userId)]
    })).filter(result => result.user);
```

```js
const results = [
  {
    "transactionId": null,
    "buyer": {
      "userId": "eu-central-1",
      "email": "pic@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "1",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf8"
    },
    "seller": {
      "userId": "eu-central-2",
      "email": "pic2@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "2",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf7"
    }
  },  {
    "transactionId": null,
    "buyer": {
      "userId": "eu-central-3",
      "email": "pic@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "1",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf8"
    },
    "seller": {
      "userId": "eu-central-4",
      "email": "pic2@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "2",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf7"
    }
  }
];

const userId = "eu-central-2";
const data = results.map(result => ({ 
        transactionId: result.transactionId, 
        user: [result.buyer, result.seller]
            [1-[result.buyer, result.seller].findIndex(user => user.userId === userId)]
    })).filter(result => result.user);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it should assign the other user not the id provided one

Comment: I see. I fixed that just now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var userId = 'eu-central-2';
var results = [
{
    "transactionId": null,
    "buyer": {
      "userId": "eu-central-1",
      "email": "pic@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "1",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf8"
    },
    "seller": {
      "userId": "eu-central-2",
      "email": "pic2@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "pic",
      "lastName": "2",
      "_id": "5902ca3ce201550655a7bbf7"
    }
  }
];
```

**If you want to remove the entire object, use this one:**

```
var data = results.filter(function(a) {
   if(a.buyer.userId == userId || a.seller.userId == userId) {
     return false;
   }
    return true;
});
```

**Or if you want to remove the specific buyer or seller, use this:**

```
var data = results.filter(function(a) {
   if(a.buyer.userId == userId) {
     delete a.buyer;
   } else if(a.seller.userId == userId) {
     delete a.seller;
   }

   if(a.buyer) {
     a['user'] = a.buyer;
     delete a.buyer;
   } else if(a.seller) {
     a['user'] = a.seller;
     delete a.seller;
   }
    return true;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Your code would work but why don't you give some explanation for the OP?

Comment: the result is same as the input

Comment: i want the object to be removed and rename it to user

Comment: You want to remove the entire object or just the buyer or seller object?

Comment: buyer or seller and replace whatever object does not have the user id as user

Comment: how can i rename it to 'user'?\

Comment: it still shows as buyer. i want to rename it to user https://jsfiddle.net/24zu0qkf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a bit more specific with your statement because javascript might not do what you expect. If I understand it correctly you want the following:

```
seller.userId === userId
OR
buyer.userId === userId
```

If that is what you want the used statement wouldnt work because JS will see it as:

```
seller.userId === true
OR
buyer.userId === userId
```

What you probebly need to do is just mention userId twice and use parenthesis like this: `(seller.userId == userId) || (buyer.userId == userId)`